# Computer occasionally complains that the hard drive could not be found. Hard drive is missing some S.M.A.R.T. data but shows no errors otherwise

Tags: hard-drive, smart

One of the computers at my workplace sometimes displays an error that the hard drive could not be found. Each time, our IT guy fixed it simply by reseating the cables. So far, the issue has not come up in almost a year.

I decided to check the hard drive's health and saw that it is missing some S.M.A.R.T. data. For example, the temperature and "power on hours" are not shown. However, there are no errors otherwise, and CrystalDiskInfo indicates that the health status is "good."

[image: CrystalDiskInfo screenshot]

I don't believe the issue is related to CrystalDiskInfo because Defraggler shows the same thing.

Anyone have an idea what could be the cause? Is this a sign that the hard drive needs to be replaced?

Comment: What exactly is your question here?

Comment: Check the drive with the drive manufacturer's drive test app and see what that tells you. That is what I would do.

Comment: @LPChip I want to determine why some S.M.A.R.T. data is not showing up, and whether this could be a sign that the hard drive is bad.

Comment: @John I downloaded Micron's official S.M.A.R.T. software. It doesn't show much information either but also indicates that the hard drive is in good health. I suspect this particular model just doesn't support certain S.M.A.R.T. attributes.

Comment: So then from your last test, the drive is apparently safe to use. Back up important files and carry on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause is an interface/connection issue - if reseating the cable fixes the problem try replace the SATA cable and/or clean the contacts and/or damp the hard drive vibration or maybe a dab with a hot glue gun to lock the connector in place.

SMART says what a drive thinks of itself, so its of inly extremely limited relevance here - what it reports or not is irrelevant to your problem.

Comment: Yeah, I'm now fairly confident that these are two different issues. I did once see an increase in error counts after a loose cable prevented one of my PCs from starting up, but this does not appear to be the case here.